# How to push back button on top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I am using a survey tool called Qualtrics and I was wondering if we can push the back button on the top left instead of bottom left, while the next button remains at the bottom

I found a code that clones the buttons. But I would only like to push the actual back button on top using JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() { jQuery('#HeaderContainer').after(jQuery('#Buttons').clone(1)); $('Header').insert($('Buttons')); });
</script>
```

Some help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the back button to just after the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() { 
  jQuery('#HeaderContainer').after(jQuery('#PreviousButton'));
});
</script>
```

However, by moving it outside the buttons div (#Buttons), you may lose css styling. Therefore, you may need to add some css to style the back button to match the next button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [prepend()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp) method:

> The jQuery `prepend()` method inserts content AT THE BEGINNING of the selected HTML elements.

```
// otherElement will be added as the first child to someElement
$('someElement').prepend(otherElement);
```